# Create and update JasperReports Server users

Tags: java, jasperserver, clarity

1. How to get the source code of create and update *JasperReports Server* roles job in 
   clarity 14.3?
2. How to redeploy the code after making changes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]If you are talking about the "Create and Update Jaspersoft Users" job this job is a Java job that is inside of proprietary CA maintained jars.  You will not be able to obtain this code so you will not have to worry about deploying it or making changes.

If you are OD (on-demand SaaS environment) you have no options other than to wait until CA gives you additional options or functionality.  In the meantime you will have to maintain your users and groups somewhat manually on the Jasper server.

If you are OP (on-premise self maintained environment) you can create a database link between the dwh and jasper or ppm and jasper database schemas and then you can create your own custom Java or GEL process to update and maintain the groups and user rights.

Comment: That I understood.I have created a pentaho etl job to create and update our own groups. but for the deletion part it is throwing error( status code 204 no content) but am not getting the error when doing the same in standard HTTP DELETE using java i can handle that . That's why I asked where to put our own jar files and how to call it inside clarity..